# Preventing NAs from being added when importing .csv files - R

Tags: r, excel, csv

I work will a lot of `.csv` files from excel. Sometimes when I import the data using

```
data=read.csv("data.csv", header=T)
```

Columns or rows of NAs will be added randomly. This seems to occur if someone used other columns during the data entry into R.

It will look like this

```
> df
   v1 v2  X X.1
1   a  1 NA  NA
2   a  1 NA  NA
3   a  1 NA  NA
4   a  0 NA  NA
5   a  0 NA  NA
6   a  0 NA  NA
7   a  1 NA  NA
8   a  1 NA  NA
9   a  0 NA  NA
10  a  0 NA  NA
11  a  1 NA  NA
12  a  0 NA  NA
13  a  1 NA  NA
14  a  1 NA  NA
15  b  1 NA  NA
16  b  1 NA  NA
17  b  0 NA  NA
18  b  0 NA  NA
19  b  0 NA  NA
20  b  0 NA  NA
21  b  0 NA  NA
22  b  0 NA  NA
23  b  0 NA  NA
24  b  1 NA  NA
25  b  1 NA  NA
26  b  1 NA  NA
27  b  1 NA  NA
28  b  1 NA  NA
```

Is there anyway to prevent these being added? Is there an argument in the `read.csv()` command?

Comment: You probably have some extra column separator in your csv file... R is importing it correctly

Answer (score 1):

If you want to strip columns with all NA values:

```
deNA <- function(df){
    df[,!sapply(df, function(col){all(is.na(col))}, simplify=TRUE),drop=FALSE]
}
```

and then:

```
foo = deNA(read.csv("data.csv",header=TRUE))
```

should do the trick:

foo.csv:

```
1,2,3,4,,,
2,3,4,5,,6,
5,4,3,2,,,
1,2,3,4,,,
```

then

```
> read.csv("foo.csv")
  X1 X2 X3 X4  X X.1 X.2
1  2  3  4  5 NA   6  NA
2  5  4  3  2 NA  NA  NA
3  1  2  3  4 NA  NA  NA

> deNA(read.csv("foo.csv"))
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X.1
1  2  3  4  5   6
2  5  4  3  2  NA
3  1  2  3  4  NA
```

Comment: A similar option: `df[ ,colSums(is.na(df)) < ncol(df)]`

Comment: Just edited to fix a bug and add `drop=FALSE` to stop one-column data frames becoming vectors. Also applies to @docendodiscimus solution. These things have probably been microbenchmarked to death and exist as solutions on SO somewhere. I reckon this is a dupe...